# Interpolated string display does not change after value updated inside setState

Tags: flutter

I am new to this and making an app as I study. Apologies if this is basic and I should be doing in a different way. Slow going wrapping my head around it all.

In the below widget I have put a function call to setSelectedCategory inside setState.
setSelectedCategory updates a boolean value on a list of ExpenseSubCategory, which is referenced when setting the icon display colour (whatever is selected displays differently).

That works fine. However I also set a string variable selectedSubCategoryTitle in that function, which displays interpolated into a Text widget string '2. Your savings on: $selectedSubCategoryTitle?',

The icon colours are all toggling nicely but the string output is not changing. What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks!

```
class SavingItemScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/saving-item';

  const SavingItemScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SavingItemScreen> createState() => _SavingItemScreenState();
}

class _SavingItemScreenState extends State<SavingItemScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    //Providers
    final expenseCategoryId =
        ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;
    final loadedCategory =
        Provider.of<ExpenseCategories>(context, listen: false)
            .findById(expenseCategoryId);
    final savingItems = Provider.of<SavingSummary>(context, listen: false);
    //

    //Copy the subcategories to a new list because the colour will change when tapped
    //however that is only on this screen to allow user selection.
    List<ExpenseSubcategory> subCat = loadedCategory.subcategories.toList();

    String selectedSubCategoryId = '';
    String selectedSubCategoryTitle = loadedCategory.title;

    /*
     Toggle the selected subcategory on the savings item builder page
     When one is selected all others must be deselected
    */
    void setSelectedCategory(String scid) {
      for (var sc in subCat) {
        if (sc.id != scid) {
          setState(
            () {
              sc.isSelected = false;
            },
          );
        } else {
          setState(() {
            sc.isSelected = true;
            selectedSubCategoryId = scid;
            selectedSubCategoryTitle = sc.title;
          });
        }
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(loadedCategory.title)),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                child: Text(
                  '1. Select your ${loadedCategory.title} category',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              //
              //Build the Grid of Icons
              //
              GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  childAspectRatio: 6 / 4,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                ),
                itemCount: subCat.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => GridTile(
                  footer: Text(
                    subCat[i].title,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  child: InkResponse(
                    enableFeedback: true,
                    onTap: () {
                      setSelectedCategory(subCat[i].id);
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                      child: Icon(
                        subCat[i].categoryIcon,
                        color:
                            subCat[i].isSelected ? Colors.amber : Colors.purple,
                        size: 60,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                child: Text(
                  '2. Your savings on: $selectedSubCategoryTitle?',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      savingItems.addItem(
                        expenseCategoryId,
                        'dummy',
                        9.99,
                        DateTime.now(),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text('SAVE'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try doing ```setState``` inside the ```setSelectedCategory``` method? Specifically inside the if and else blocks, and let us know how it goes?

Comment: I updated to that (will update the code above) but no difference. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see where the error is. It is really hard to debug this code on my machine since you have a lot of dependencies not included inside the shared code bit :).
Can you try moving:

```
List<ExpenseSubcategory> subCat = loadedCategory.subcategories.toList();
String selectedSubCategoryId = '';
String selectedSubCategoryTitle = loadedCategory.title;
```

outside of the `build` method?

I want you to do this because when the state rebuilds itself, i.e. a state changed inside (meaning you updated one of the local states), everything inside the build method is called again, in this case you setting the `subCat`, `selectedSubCategoryId` and `selectedSubCategoryTitle` are reassigned.

In conclusion, whatever you want to remain as a local state, i.e. within the boundaries of the `StatefulWidget` leave them outside the build method, as you want to update them and not reassign them to their original values.

You might ask what about the Providers. Well for them you could create them as final variables inside the build method, since they're never changing, and when the state is rebuilt those variables will not be reassigned since they were declared as final.

You can't do the same for `subCat`, `selectedSubCategoryId` and `selectedSubCategoryTitle` since they local to `_SavingItemScreenState`  and are bound to be updated throughout the lifecycle of the State.

Hope this answers the question :). Feel free to let me know if you need any more clarification!

Edit: To listen to Providers inside `initState`:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  final loadedCategory = Provider.of<ExpenseCategories>(context, listen: false).findById(expenseCategoryId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. I have the issue that loadedCategory is set inside the build method. The category is selected in the previous screen from a list of options, and in this screen the user then will fill in the details and save a new SavingItem. 

subcategory options are displayed depending on whatever parent category(loadedCategory) the screen opens with. So if it's "Food and Drink" then subcategories are "Beer", "Cafe" etc. I had been copying them to a new list because the isSelected state is only for this data entry

I understand the issue now but not sure how to resolve.

Comment: You can listen to Providers inside ```initState``` too :). Check my edited answer. One thing that does not make sense inside me is that you're using Providers but you're not updating variables inside Providers, but rather with local states. Why do that when you could persist all changes throughout all screens? Of course assuming you'll need those changes later on.

Comment: Thank you!

One last question I hope. If I declare the variable inside init state I wasn't able to refer to it in my build method. 

So I declared outside of init state, but flutter prompted me to use late in the declaration. That leads to this error, which weirdly if I then click the code and save (hot reload) resolves and works fine (with the original issue resolved!).  .......
The following LateError was thrown building SavingItemScreen(dirty, state: _SavingItemScreenState#b3d25):
LateInitializationError: Field 'loadedCategory' has not been initialized.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/yYS9tmdd/Screenshot-1679890557.png

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/prQ9VZnY/Screenshot-2023-03-27-at-5-15-26-PM.png

Comment: Hey @nktokyo sorry for the late reply. Yes that variable should be loaded before it is used, if it is a late variable. Another way would be using nullable variables. Both would work, but before using nullable types please check if it is null beforehand. Otherwise for late variables you have to pinpoint when to use them i.e. when they have been initialised and are not empty :)

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get it to work so I reasked the question more simply. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872215/dropdown-based-on-data-passed-to-widget-provider-as-argument

Comment: Seems like the post was removed by you, so I'm guessing you got it working :).